# Grabbing number from numbered list and pasting in Document

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working in HotDocs, a document template creation software. I am looking for a way to insert a previous number into the template, as it's a legal form and need to say "Paragraphs 1 - _ are true." The number can change depending on conditions, so was wondering if there's a way for Word to copy the number in. If not we can write it in. Like this:

[image]

I would need the 72 to fill in the highlighted space, but that number can change because there are several different special counts that fill in on conditions. Any ideas for how to do this? I could reformat the numbered list as a field so that I have more control over it, but there are other issues with that that I don't feel would be worth the effort. Thank you!

The HotDocs scripting language being used has basic coding capabilities, IF statements and loops and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used an outline numbered style for your paragraph numbering, then a STYLEREF field with a \n switch will give you the current paragraph number, which is one more than the final number that you want.

So you can use that STYLEREF field inside an =(Formula) field to subtract 1 from that result.

[image]